# How to keep running a program in Java

Tags: java

I have written some Java code to keep getting some value in other website every 10sec.
And I will keep writing the result to append a txt file.
How can I keep running this code.
Should I run it in some cloud server?
If so, how can I do it.
I just know in Eclipse, I click "run application".
How can I run in other ways(Linux, or without Eclipse)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do, using a loop, shell script and a cron job to achieve what you need:

1. Make sure your program has the logic something like an infinite loop to run always.
2. Then write a shell script to invoke your java program with the necessary arguments.
3. Make sure that the classpath argument points to the jars that you need.
4. Make sure that the shell script has necessary linux permissions.
5. Schedule the script to be invoked by setting up a cron job. You can set the cron condition as per your need.

Comment: how to stop the program?

Comment: @jjLin http://superuser.com/questions/204568/how-to-stop-all-instances-of-cron

Answer (score 1):

If you used eclipse, then you probably have created a jar file.  In that case to run it outside eclipse:

```
java -jar <path-to-jar-file.jar>
```

Make sure you are in the correct folder before running above.

Comment: how to stop the program?

Comment: That will be another question :-)

Comment: CONTROL-C should work :-)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is an IDE, meaning it allows you to edit and run code. When you click the `Play` button to run a project in eclipse, for each of your *.java files in the project workspace, another *.class file gets created. This is your code compiled to something the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) understands, and can be translated into machine languange and be ran.

These .class files can be run from the command line as well:

```
java myProgram.class
```

(Assuming you have the JRE in your environment variables). This can be done from any jvm on any platform, as long as your code is designed to be cross platform (Not using Windows specific APIs for example).

To stop the app, you can either implement a method that stops it, or kill its process. As for cloud computing, this is too broad a topic to just shoot you an answer here, but yes, you can run your code on a linux machine for example.